# Add count as select field using jooq SelectQuery

Tags: java, jooq

Most of the existing posts I can find dealing with my learning jook are outdated.

I'm trying to build dynamically so that I can use conditions for certain changes. I'm trying to find how to add `COUNT(*)` to an existing list of fields

```
SelectQuery query = create().selectQuery();
query.addSelect(TABLE.FIELD);
// add COUNT(*)?
```

I'm not seeing any methods or API help on how to do this when building the query dynamically.

Comment: Could you link to a couple of outdated posts? That way, they can be edited and rectified...

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`DSL.count()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#count%28%29)

```
query.addSelect(count());
```

The above is assuming a static import as such:

```
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Comment: I'm trying to write `SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER() FROM table1 ... JOIN table 2 ... JOIN table3` and the only way I can get the equivalent of the `*` is to do `create().select( TABLE1.fields() ).select( TABLE2.fields() ).select( TABLE3.fields() ).select( count().over() )`.  Unfortunately, `create.select().select( count().over() )` only returns the `count` field.  Is there a more concise way to write this?

Comment: @JoshPadnick: The "standalone asterisk" is usually only supported by itself, not in combination with other columns. So in most SQL dialects, the query you're trying to write wouldn't work either. However, there's a trick. If you ask a new question, I'll elaborate (comment is not well-suited for this).

Comment: Done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313595/jooq-concisely-representing-both-columns-and-aggregate-window-functions-in-a-q.  Thanks for your assistance, Lukas!