# jOOQ - Concisely Representing Both Columns and Aggregate/Window Functions in a Query

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

This post comes as a result of a comment I left on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19860271/2308858

I'm using PostgreSQL and jOOQ 3.4 and trying to represent the following SQL query in jOOQ:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER() 
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
JOIN table3 t3 ON (t1.otherId = t3.otherId)
```

I like how Postgres lets me concisely represent "all columns plus the `count` column" with nothing more than `SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER()`.  But when I try to represent this same query in jOOQ, the most concise way I can do is:

```
create.select( TABLE1.fields() ).select( TABLE2.fields() ).select( TABLE3.fields() ).select( count().over() )
   .from( TABLE1 )
   .join( TABLE2 ).on( TABLE1.ID.equal( TABLE2.ID ))
   .join( TABLE3 ).on( TABLE1.OTHER_ID.equal( TABLE3.OTHER_ID ))
```

Ideally, I'd write this instead:

```
create.select().select( count().over() )
   .from( TABLE1 )
   .join( TABLE2 ).on( TABLE1.ID.equal( TABLE2.ID ))
   .join( TABLE3 ).on( TABLE1.OTHER_ID.equal( TABLE3.OTHER_ID ))
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution, which you've found yourself, is indeed the way to go with the jOOQ API:

```java
create.select( TABLE1.fields() )
      .select( TABLE2.fields() )
      .select( TABLE3.fields() )
      .select( count().over() )
      ...
```

It conceptually corresponds to this valid SQL query:

```sql
SELECT table1.*, table2.*, table3.*, COUNT(*) OVER()
...
```

#### Manipulating the jOOQ "model API":

But if this is annoying to you, you can also work around this issue with this little trick:

```java
// Get access to the "model API" from a statement without any SELECT fields
SelectQuery<?> select =
create.select()
      .from( TABLE1 )
      .join( TABLE2 ).on( TABLE1.ID.equal( TABLE2.ID ))
      .join( TABLE3 ).on( TABLE1.OTHER_ID.equal( TABLE3.OTHER_ID ))
      .getQuery();

// Copy all fields from the SELECT statement:
List<Field<?>> fields = new ArrayList<>(select.getSelect());

// And explicitly add them:
select.addSelect(fields);
select.addSelect(count().over());
```

This is equally verbose as your original attempt, but might be a bit simpler to use, generically.

#### Using a derived table

Of course, you could also simply write the following, equivalent SQL query, which would be more standard SQL:

```sql
SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
  JOIN table3 t3 ON (t1.otherId = t3.otherId)
) t
```

With jOOQ, this would translate to:

```java
Table<?> t = select()
            .from( TABLE1 )
            .join( TABLE2 ).on( TABLE1.ID.equal( TABLE2.ID ))
            .join( TABLE3 ).on( TABLE1.OTHER_ID.equal( TABLE3.OTHER_ID ))
            .asTable("t");

create.select(t.fields(), count().over())
      .from(t);
```

#### Support for the asterisk

In a future version of jOOQ, [the actual asterisk (`*`) might be supported explicitly through the jOOQ API](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2769). At this point, it is a bit unclear how that can be achieved syntactically, though.

#### On a side-note:

I have always found it very curious that PostgreSQL allows this syntax here:

```sql
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER() 
...
```

It is hardly ever supported by SQL engines and a bit "unpredictable". Neither does the SQL standard allow for a "standalone asterisk" to be combined with other column expressions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Lukas!  Since I'm not reusing this field set multiple places, it sounds like the original syntax is best.    Great to know the other options on the table.